# Hang while streaming to my Playstation 3 using Nero

Tags: troubleshooting, freeze, ps3, nero

I use Nero to stream media to my PS3 from 2 main computers. Occasionally it will hang when the host computer is in sleep/hibernate. It resumes fine if you manually wake up the computer. Any suggestions on a workaround for this?

Comment: Update: unfortunately changing the computer to wake on LAN activity didn't fix the problem as I had hoped, but I was able to get around the problem by setting the computer & monitor to never go to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Can you set the computer to wake on LAN activity? Or do you have it set that way and it is working intermittently?

Sorry if you already have this set up.

Comment: no, i was unaware of this setting but was exactly something i was hoping for. i've set that up and will give it a go!!